# Does .gitignore have an equivalent for version controlled files?

Tags: git

This question is *related* to the following questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[git]+%2Bassume-unchanged, however, none of the provided answers to these questions seem to meet my needs.

I have a header file (key_info.h) that gets generated by a python script. To be clever, I version controlled a placeholder version of the header (key_info.h) with a single line of code:

```
int i = you_need_to_run_the_key_info_gen_python_script_to_generate_this_file();
```

Prior to running the python script, compiling this code will yield an error telling the developer exactly what to do; run the script.

Naturally, the developer will proceed by running the python script to generate the latest version of key_info.h and the code will successfully compile.  The developer will then go on to make a series of changes and then 'git commit' their code.

The problem we run into is the fact that key_info.h has now been modified.  As such, git will pick it up as a modification and will allow it to be committed.  However, the generated version of this header should never be version controlled.  We need the placeholder version to remain unchanged to continue to provide the compile error hint to developers.

My first instinct was to use .gitignore to prevent git from picking up key_info.h in a commit.  .gitignore is then easily shared between developers since .gitignore itself is version controlled.  Unfortunately, .gitignore only works for files that aren't version controlled.

My next thought was to use 'git update-index --assume-unchanged /path/to/file'.  This works great locally, but I have no way of enforcing this rule upon other developers.  It's only a matter of time before a dev accidentally commits the generated header.

**So my question is this:** is there a way to version control a file, while silently enforcing a rule that the file is to be ignored when it comes time to commit changes?  What I really want is .gitignore for version controlled files.

Comment: I would recommend separating the template file from the generated file by renaming the template file. Then an unconfigured build will faile due to a missing file (which, with some work, could be made to act similarly to what you have now), but the presence of the file could be safely completely ignored by your version control system, because the generated file would have a different and distinct file name from the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I have no way of enforcing this rule upon other developers

You do, almost: you could make your key-info-gen script run `git update-index --assume-unchanged /some/path`.

But I don't think this is a good idea.

I would probably opt for not overwriting the header file at all. Let your Python script generate the correct header file and write it into a *different* directory, and pass `-I` compiler options for both of those directories, in the right order. If the script has not been run, the version-controlled header will be found. If the script has been run, the user-generated header will be found. And you can then put the path of the user-generated header in `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 3):

Some alternatives, ranked and tl;dr'd by some guy you've never met:

- The *best* way to do this is to simply not track the file at all, because what you have is a makefile target.  If you can't get or don't want a `make` ... well, any IDE can configure build recipes, right?

  [@hvd has the best version of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23835371/1290731), I missed it at first: put generated headers in a .gitignored `generated-headers` directory you get your compiler to search first, and keep the default as backup.
- If your build process isn't amenable to that, next best is [the filter method @VonC describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23835409/1290731), because it's robust against temporarily checking out a branch that doesn't have that file. The tl;dr on the filters is  "preserve what's there":

  ```
  git config filter.pin-content.clean  'git show HEAD:%f 2>&- || cat'
  git config filter.pin-content.smudge 'cat %f           2>&- || cat' 

  echo anypatternyouwant filter=pin-content >>.gitattributes  # tracked, global
  echo anypatternyouwant filter=pin-content >>.git/info/attributes # local-only
  ```

  *Note well:* [git will silently ignore filters that aren't configured](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_tt_filter_tt), so giving a file
  a tracked attribute will work, it will have no effect on others until they want it to.
- Next best is the canonical method, much the easiest to implement and works a treat so long as the file is tracked on all branches:

  ```
  git update-index --assume-unchanged key_info.h
  ```

  but when you temporarily switch to a branch that doesn't track that file it will lose this protection on return.

Answer (score 1):

> This works great locally, but I have no way of enforcing this rule upon other developers

The other way is to declare a content filter driver which would, on `git add`, automatically restore your file to the appropriate content.

[image: http://git-scm.com/figures/18333fig0703-tn.png]

<sup>(From [Pro Git book 7.2 Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion))</sup>

You can store and share:

- the declaration of the filter in a [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).
- the '`clean`' script which will restore the content

But: each user would still have to register that filter in their local config:

```
git config filter.<filtername>.clean ./<filterscript>
```

So there is no universal way to "ignore" a versioned file, only local solution to be applied in each repo.

---

Those same filter can help you:

- version a  `key_info.h.tpl`
- generate on checkout (smudge script) a `key_info.h` which remains private

---

You don't always have to store a script, since it can be in the filter declaration itself, as [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835272/does-gitignore-have-an-equivalent-for-version-controlled-files/23835409?noredirect=1#comment36678001_23835409):

> for this, since 1.8.5 the filters get the pathname and you can make the filter setup self-contained.
>
> For instance:

```
git config filter.pin-content.clean 'git show HEAD:%f 2>&- || cat'
git config filter.pin-content.smudge 'cat %f 2>&- || cat'
```

> That will preserve the destination content if any else used what's supplied.
>   Then:
>
> - `echo anypatternyoulike filter=pin-content >>.git/info/attributes` to make the filter local, or
> - `...>>.gitattributes` to make it global.

Comment: Note: for this, since 1.8.5 the filters get the pathname and you can make the filter setup self-contained, for instance `git config filter.pin-content.clean 'git show HEAD:%f 2>&- || cat'` and `git config filter.pin-content.smudge 'cat %f 2>&- || cat'` which will preserve the destination content if any else used what's supplied.  Then `echo anypatternyoulike filter=pin-content >>.git/info/attributes` to make the filter local, or `...>>.gitattributes` to make it global.

Comment: @jthill Good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.