# Is there a way to have a patch that is never commited, only changes the working copy?

Tags: git

I would like to modify a test to comment in some extra code:

```
-        /*SimpleMonitor monitor = new SimpleMonitor();
-        machine.attachMonitor(monitor);*/
+        SimpleMonitor monitor = new SimpleMonitor();
+        machine.attachMonitor(monitor);
```

That is, when I am building locally I would like to enable SimpleMonitor, but I always want the checked in code to keep it commented out. SimpleMonitor prints out some verbose information about what is going on internally in my test cases.

Of course I can just never add this change to the commit.

Is there a way with git that I can always exclude this change, even when using 'git add .' or 'git add -A' and so on, such that git will skip over this change?

The idea is that this is a delta that sits on top of a working copy only. If there is some neat trick with stash or using a branch or something else, do please tell me about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare for your file a content filter driver ( a 'clean' script) which would automatically, on checkin, comment the right line.
That is done in a [`.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file: see for instance "[Does `.gitignore` have an equivalent for version controlled files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23835409/6309)".

[image: clean]

<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes)" from the [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/))</sup>

```
git config filter.<filtername>.clean ./<filterscript>
```

You can have `<filterscript>` versioned in your repo.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like it will do the trick. Unlike the other question, I do't have to enforce this on other users either, its just for my local testing.

Comment: @user2800708 yes, that will be local only to your repo, because the `git config` which declares that filter won't impact other repos. So even if the .gitattributes and scripts are in your repo, the filter won't run unless you explicitly declares it in the *local* config of your repo.