# Run external tool before GIT commit in PHPStorm

Tags: git, batch-file, phpstorm

Our project uses gettext to allow for multiple languages. Further, there is a *.bat and *.sh file, which generates the current POT file both from the PHP files and Smarty templates.

Is there a way to configure PHPStorm to execute an external tool (for example the bat file), **before** doing a GIT commit? In the commit window, there is only the possibility to execute a tool after commit. However, after doing changes in the code, I would like to update the POT first, then commit the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the [clean step of a content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24329656/6309):

[image: clean]

<sup>(image shown in "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The commit would trigger the `clean` script in order to modify the files, *before* the commit.

The `clean` script is:

- declared with `git config filter.<filtername>.clean ./<filterscript>`
- used in a [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this indeed looks very promising. One question, though: We have developers working under UNIX and Windows, hence there is a *.bat file and an *.sh file. Both essentially do the same job. Is there a way in the `.gitattributes` file to execute the batch file when in Windows environment and the shell script when in UNIX?

Comment: @waza-ari no, the clean script should be a bash one, not a `.bat`. Even on Windows.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much @VonC. It works now, I will accept the answer. Just have a little problem with line endings remaining, but I will look for other answers or post a new question.

Comment: one more question please: is it possible to declare the filter "automatically" using a file from repository? Now, the .gitattributes file, which uses the filter is checked in the repository, as well as the bash script. I would like to "automate" the filter setup for new developers, such that after checkout the filter is both declared and used.

Comment: @waza-ari you cannot "automate" the config which is; by definition, local. You only can put in a README that the user should add an include directive (which can point to a versionned config file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9733277/6309)