# Commit within a pre-push to update version

Tags: git, githooks

I am using a `pre-push` hook that copies some files around and uses `grunt bump` to up the version number on my package prior to zipping it up. This all happens on the `master` branch and the assumption is that because it's a push on `master`, it's worthy of a patch version increase and zips up my Chrome extension to include all the necessary files.

The issue I am running into is that the version is modified too late for it to be committed for the hook to include it in the push, thus my next commit is always 1 patch version behind what is actually tagged.

What solution do I have here? This is a single-user project so I am not worried too much about going against how the hook is intended to be used. Would an option be to commit and a sub push, and then return non-zero from this hook to prevent the push from happening?

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin

BRANCH="$1"
EXTENSION_PATH=./extension
SCRIPT_PATH=$EXTENSION_PATH/script/


if [ "$branch" == "master" ]
then

    # remove the existing script folder; we'll just re-populate it
    echo "Removing existing scripts..."
    rm -rf $EXTENSION_PATH/script

    echo "Making target directory: $SCRIPT_PATH"
    mkdir $SCRIPT_PATH

    echo "Copying script files..."
    cp config.js $SCRIPT_PATH
    cp supportportal.js $SCRIPT_PATH
    cp -r ./scripts/ $SCRIPT_PATH/scripts/

    # bump the version
    grunt bump

    # commit changes and push here
    # >>>

    # if on a tag, append that to the filename
    VERSION=$(git describe --tags --always)

    # get name of the most top folder of git repo directory,
    # combine with revision tail
    OUTPUT=extension-$VERSION.zip

    # building archive
    zip -r -X $OUTPUT $EXTENSION_PATH 

    echo "Done!";
fi

exit 0 #exit 1 instead of 0 to cancel original push?
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a [client-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_client_side_hooks) like a `pre-push` or even a `pre-commit` one, another alternative is to use a content filter driver, specifically the 'clean' one, which is run automatically on `git commit`.

I proposed that in "[Why is the index not updated after doing a git add in a `pre-commit` hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29362985/6309)"... but that would not capture the last commit (in `git describe`), ... since said last commit is being built.

Instead, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29368069/6309), a `post-commit` hook could be used to (if it is run in the right branch) detect the version change and add/update the version file.